# What does "an optional list of variables protected by the memory barrier" mean in Intel documentation?

Tags: c, gcc, intel, atomic, gnu

From GCC documentation for the legacy `__sync` builtins: [Built-in functions for atomic memory access](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html), there is a quote “an optional list of variables protected by the memory barrier” described in the *Intel Itanium Processor-specific Application Binary Interface*. What does it mean?

> All of the routines are are described in the Intel documentation to
>   take **“an optional list of variables protected by the memory barrier”**.
>   It's not clear what is meant by that; it could mean that *only* the
>   following variables are protected, or it could mean that these
>   variables should in addition be protected. At present GCC ignores this
>   list and protects all variables which are globally accessible. If in
>   the future we make some use of this list, an empty list will continue
>   to mean all globally accessible variables.

The `__atomic` builtins that make `__sync` obsolete don't have this, but what was the original design that `__sync` builtins inherited the optional list from?

Comment: The compiler is free to re-order statements (for optimization) as long as the "visible effect" doesn't change. An access to an atomic variable has to be considered respectively concerning re-ordering. (It can be imagined like a "barrier" which has to be considered in that re-ordering.) It sounds like Intel planned (designed) an option to specify (or exclude) variables explicitly which are considered for such a barrier.

Comment: If you are asking what Intel meant by this, then you'll probably have to ask Intel.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield And they probably won't have an answer either, seeing as that language appeared in the manual for a product which was discontinued earlier this year.

Comment: You linked the ancient gcc4.1 manual.  But the current version of that section of the GCC manual still has the same language.  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fsync-Builtins.html.  (But the section is renamed *Legacy `__sync` Built-in Functions for Atomic Memory Access* because the [`__atomic` builtins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html) are intended to replace them.  `__atomic` builtins don't have that optional list; they have a `memorder` parameter that works like C++11 `memory_order_relaxed`/`acquire`/`release`/`acq_rel`/`seq_cst`.